# Struggling to import analyst share price to GoogleSheets

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, stock

I am trying to create a column that imports the analyst price target from TipRanks website.
I uploaded two images:

[Image 1: you can see the cell that I want to import.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDnoQ.jpg)

[Image 2: you can see my function that doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAa2m.png)

What should I change in order to get this live info?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please do not include images in your question, but rather a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). OItherwise no one can copy paste what you have tried and you are very unlikely to get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you are checking is actually "javascript" generated thus import functions won't properly work on them.

To check, just try to import the whole site data. If it returns a javascript function, then it is javascript generated.

Sample (`tipranks.com`)

[image: Sample]

What you can do is actually try to find other sites that provide the same data.

I did find one with the same data you are looking for, **50.38** for **csiq**. Link is "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/csiq/analystestimates". And since data is shown as table, it would be easier to import using `importhtml`.

Cell formula is:
`=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/csiq/analystestimates", "table", 5), 2, 2)`

Sample output:
[image: sample output]

The table is the fifth one in the `DOM`, and `INDEX(table, 2, 2)` means getting the 2nd row 2nd column of the table.

If the site is no good for you, you can try finding other sites that would suit your needs. And then use either `importhtml` or `importxml` depending on the site structure.

Comment: First of all - thank you so much for your answer. It's good enough for me right now. Is there any way to make this formula smarter? instead of editing the name of the stock manually, is there any way to do it like this (A2 - cells in my table): =INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/A2/analystestimates", "table", 5), 2, 2)

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. For your question, you can reference the cell by doing this: `=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/"&A2&"/analystestimates", "table", 5), 2, 2)`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the network when the website is loading you will see that the prices come when calling the forecast endpoint `https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/tsla/forecast`. This in turn returns an html response which is probably generated with Javascript on the client because they use React on the frontend, but you can still see the preview in the Network tab of the browser dev tools.

You can then copy the preview in VSCode and prettify it, to try and pin point the span holding the price. Of course it won't be exact science, because the html tags are generated with some media queries, but you will get close enough to some extent.

After you get the xml path but you get an empty error, you can delete some tags until you get some text. Use search in google sheets to search for highest price label, and than continue adding tags until you get the desired value.

Here is what I managed to get:
Lowest price target:
`=importxml("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/snow/forecast", "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/span[2]")`

Average price target:
`=importxml("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/snow/forecast", "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/span[2]")`

Highest price target:
`=importxml("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/snow/forecast", "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]")`

In time these methods might change depending on their development process, but you could use the above steps to update the script.

P.S. I wasn't satisfied with the marketwatch analyst price targets. I think the wisdom of the crowd is better on tipranks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Works perfectly fine on my personal Stock Portfolio on Google Sheets:

Lowest Price Target:

```
=importxml(CONCATENATE("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/", A1,"/forecast"), "//*[@class='colorpurple-dark  ml3 mobile_fontSize7 laptop_ml0']")
```

Average Price Target:

```
=importxml(CONCATENATE("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/", A4,"/forecast"), "//*[@class='colorgray-1  ml3 mobile_fontSize7 laptop_ml0']")
```

Highest Price Target:

```
=importxml(CONCATENATE("https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/", A4,"/forecast"), "//*[@class='colorpale  ml3 mobile_fontSize7 laptop_ml0']")
```